# Row number partition by to POWER BI DAX query

Tags: powerbi, dax, rownum

Can someone help me to convert the sql string to Dax?

**row_number() p over (partition by date, customer, type order by day)**[image]

The row number is my desired output.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your data looks like this table:

```
Sample
+------------+----------+---------+--------+
|    Date    | Customer | Product | Gender |
+------------+----------+---------+--------+
| 01/01/2018 |     1234 | P2      | F      |
| 01/01/2018 |     1234 | P2      | M      |
| 03/01/2018 |     1235 | P1      | F      |
| 03/01/2018 |     1235 | P2      | F      |
+------------+----------+---------+--------+
```

I have created a calculated column called Rank, using the RANKX and FILTER function.

The first part of the calculation is to create variables outside the scope of the FILTER function. The second part uses RANKX that takes an expression value - in this case Gender -  to order the values.

```
Rank = 
VAR _currentdate = 'Sample'[Date]
VAR _customer = 'Sample'[Customer]
var _product = 'Sample'[Product]

return
RANKX(FILTER('Sample',
[Date]=_currentdate &&
[Customer] = _customer &&
[Product] = _product),[Gender],,ASC)
```

The output is

[image]

I contrasted the output to the SQL equivalent.

```
select 
*, 
row_number() over(partition by Date,Customer,Product order by Gender) 
from (
select '2018-01-01' as Date,1234 as CUSTOMER,'P2' AS PRODUCT, 'M' Gender union
select '2018-01-01' as Date,1234,'P2','F' UNION
select '2018-01-03' as Date,1235,'P1','F' UNION
  select '2018-01-03' as Date,1235,'P2','F' 
)t1
```

[image]

Comment: The PARTITION BY will be your filters and your ORDER BY will be the expression.

Comment: Can this be done in M (Power Query)?