# DAX - Reference Columns in a Virtual Table

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

How can I reference the columns of a table stored in a DAX variable? Including my code below- thank you!

```
measure = 

VAR min_dates = 

//get the min order date for each customer
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Orders[Customer ID],"min_date",MIN(Orders[Order Date]))

RETURN

min_dates

// what I want to do here is take the table I created above (min_dates) and do the following: 
// 1) group_by min_date
// 2) count(distinct) Customer ID

// What I'm struggling with is how to reference the columns created in the min_dates table above.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data looks like this:

```
Orders
+------------+---------+------------+
| CustomerID | OrderID | Order Date |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 1          | 1       | 25/07/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 2          | 2       | 26/07/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 3          | 3       | 27/07/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 4          | 4       | 28/07/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 4          | 5       | 29/07/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 5          | 6       | 30/07/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 6          | 7       | 31/07/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 6          | 8       | 01/08/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 7          | 9       | 01/08/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 7          | 10      | 03/08/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 8          | 11      | 03/08/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 9          | 12      | 04/08/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 10         | 13      | 05/08/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 11         | 14      | 05/08/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 11         | 15      | 06/08/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 12         | 16      | 06/08/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
| 12         | 17      | 06/08/2020 |
+------------+---------+------------+
```

I assumed you want to calculate new customers. I have created a measure that solves the issue using `RANKX`. From the pair of values CustomerID and Order Date, the calculation takes the first date for each CustomerID. In other words, and using SQL nomenclature, `RANKX` is partition by CUSTOMERID and OrderBy Order Date.
The measure would create a table on the fly, adding a column to rank each CustomerID and Order Date pair. The rank would count the number of orders for each customer.
The second step uses `DISTINCTCOUNT` for CustomerID when the rank created on the table is equal to 1.

```
UniqueCustomers =
VAR t1 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        orders,
        "Rank", RANKX (
            FILTER ( ALL ( Orders ), [CustomerID] = EARLIER ( Orders[CustomerID] ) ),
            [Order Date],
            ,
            ASC,
            DENSE
        )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Orders[CustomerID] ), FILTER ( t1, [Rank] = 1 ) )
```

Comment: This is great, thank you for taking a look at this. Going through this will be a good learning experience for me - can I ask how you'd do this with my original approach as well? I am still curious around how to reference columns from a DAX "Temp Table". Thanks again.

Comment: I think your approach is closer to SQL way of thinking  rather than DAX. I'm not sure how to replicate your calculation because `DISTINCTCOUNT` doesn't have an equivalent for tables, such as `COUNTX`.

Comment: A follow up - can you help me understand what table this is returning: 


`FILTER ( ALL ( Orders ), Orders[Customer ID] = EARLIER ( Orders[Customer ID] ) )`


I tried to run that piece on its own as a table, but I guess it doesn't have all the context that EARLIER needs to work. I'm trying to learn about EARLIER, seeing that intermediate table would've been useful :(

Comment: The table returned is used for `RANKX`. The filter is applied to do the partitioning by `CustomerID`. In this example, you can see the partitioning for `RANKX` as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63102302/row-number-partition-by-to-power-bi-dax-query/63106896#63106896
`EARLIER` is used to access to the context of each row, usually is considered an "old" practice in DAX code, but in that case, I thought it was cleaner than the alternative of using variables.